# Building library with optional storybook application in angular

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm writing an angular library using Angular 16
I created angular workspace with projects folder.
this is the structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4LlQ.png)

As you can understand from folder naming i'm trying to implement an angular application that use storybook to have a visual documentation for my library components.
At the moment i install my library using npm install command and i don't import storybook by default. Also the storybook work properly in workspace.
I want use my library in another angular project and use storybook application only using command like 'npm install de-std-lib/storybook-app'.

But i have this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uulXX.png)

Anyone now how i can proceed ?

I tried to create storybook package with npm pack and building library
I publish only my lib and not storybook_application